# Can't add www page to google adsense

Tags: redirect, https, dns, adsense, vercel

I have website hosted on zeit. I bought domain, but it can only be accessible via https://www.example.com but when i try to enter my websites name to google adsense it keeps downgrading to https://example.com, so, because of that verification always fails. How to solve this? How to change dns settings to redirect https.. to https://www..? Or is it possible to prevent downgrade to https? I'm basically failing first step of adsense registration.

Comment: did you find any solution?